# Batch repacking zip archives into 7z

Tags: windows-7, batch, archiving

I have many `zip` archive files that I would like to re-pack into `7z` archive format, as that would save me a lot of space. How do I batch-repack those files on a Windows 7 computer?

I tried doing this via GUI version of 7-zip archiver, but I didn't find a corresponding function. WinRar has a "Convert" functionality, but it doesn't archive into `7z` format.

I'm not asking exclusively for a solution involving Batch-file scripting.

Comment: Uhmm, write a batch file that uses 7-zip?  What have you tired already? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my own take on the problem:

`for %%F in (*.zip) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%F_tmp" "%%F" * & pushd %%F_tmp & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -r -t7z ..\"%%~nF".7z * & popd & rmdir /s /q "%%F_tmp" )`

Save this to a `zip to 7z.bat` file, place it into the directory with all the zip files you want to convert and double-click it there.

Thanks to Clint Priest for the base code.

Comment: How would I augment this to perform on both .rar and .zip?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to add a command to then delete the previous file?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor just replace `(*.zip)` with `(*.rar)` and run that version too. As for deleting, I wouldn't recommend doing it in this script for safety. Unless you have backups, you might lose the files if they don't get converted, since this script doesn't have any error handling. Just check if you have the same number of new and old archives by sorting by date and selecting the newly created archives and comparing the number to total files in folder (minus the batch script file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 7zip command line (detailed examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)) to first extract all files/folders (using the `e` command) and then re-compress them to 7z (using the `a` command).

If you plan on repeating this operation, consider capturing the command lines in a .bat/.cmd file.

And always test on a small directory before trying on a huge number of archives!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command line that will do it for you, this assumes that the zip files are in the same directory as 7z.exe:

`for %F in (*.zip) do ( 7z.exe e -y -o%~nF.tmp %F * & pushd %~nF.tmp & ..\7z.exe a -y -r -t7z ..\%~nF * & popd & rmdir /s /q %~nF.tmp )`

Comment: I'm still struggling to make this work for me.

Comment: What problem are you having?  The above snippet assumes your .zip files are in the 7-zip program directory.  You should run that command from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Alternatively put your zips in an unprotected directory, replace the 7z.exe references with the full path to the 7z.exe.  Then from a regular cmd prompt cd into the dir with your zip files and run the modified snippet.

Comment: I just did it and it compresses the files in the folder the bat file is being run from (1 test zip archive and the bat file itself). After which it says 2 times "cannot find specified file".

Comment: Well, I tried `for %%F in (*.zip) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -y -o%%~nF.tmp %%F * )` and it says `cannot find archive` for all zip files in folder.

Comment: Wont work with the double %%F as far as my testing went.  I may have a mistake in my original post with that * at the end of the first 7z command (extract command).

Comment: I'm saving the code to .bat file in the target directory and running it from there. Batch scripts require double `%`s if run from a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

user1306322 answer was super helpful for me, thanks!!
I just wanted to convert from rar to zip so I changed the extensions and it worked lke a charm

```
for %%F in (*.rar) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%F_tmp" "%%F" * & pushd %%F_tmp & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -r -tzip ..\"%%~nF".zip * & popd & rmdir /s /q "%%F_tmp" )
```

And then I wanted to delete the files, they said in the convo that it is better not to in case something can't be converted because it would be deleted and lost, but I had to do this many times (Many folders with diferents mangas) so deleting them afterwards was a lot of work and I preferred to take the risk
I added a line below like this

```
del *.rar
```

And that's it, everything done!
The only thing is that I have to go folder by folder and execute the scripts, I wonder if I could add something to just run it in the parent Manga directory and it would do the trick in all subfolders...

Anyways I just want to comment that I did this to convert the files from .cbr to .cbz, so the final code is what user1306322 did plus a renaming line before and afterwards

```
ren *.cbr *.rar
for %%F in (*.rar) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%F_tmp" "%%F" * & pushd %%F_tmp & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -r -tzip ..\"%%~nF".zip * & popd & rmdir /s /q "%%F_tmp" )
ren *.zip *.cbz
del *.rar
```

So if anyone is reading this and doesn't know how to code like me, these are the instructions to batch convert cbr to cbz: First install 7zip, then just create a text file (.txt) in the folder you have the files to be converted, open it and paste the code just above inside, save and close and then rename the extension ".txt" to ".bat", something like "cbr to cbz.bat". Double click this "cbr to cbz.bat" file and voilà!