# How can I copy identically-named files out of a series of folders, and append the folder name to the filename to disambiguate?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My source folder contains directories containing files like this (each file has the same name):

```
dir1\f
dir2\f
dir3\f
...
```

I would like to copy all files named `f` to another directory, renamed as follows:

```
dir1-f
dir2-f
dir3-f
```

Can I do this using a Windows batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for /d %F in (*) do @copy /y "%F\f" "\someFolder\%F-f" 2>nul
```

Or

```
for /d %F in (*) do @if exist "%F\f" copy /y "%F\f" "\someFolder\%F-f"
```

Double up the percents if used in a batch file

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in a batch file, open up a command prompt and type for /?, there are numerous examples on google to do this type of thing.

Comment: -1 if/when you have the rep to comment, then that may have been worthy of a comment(though i doubt it was even worthy of that), but certainly not worthy of an answer. The comment might've gone like -I don't know, or I don't know off hand off hand-, followed by but try for /?. But  I wouldn't even have done that comment because enough people know it involves for and can answer. a comment would've been okish.. but for /? is totally unworthy of being an answer.

Comment: I see, well i can provide an example then.  I have read others flaming for providing the batch command to do it.

Comment: be interesting to see the link to that "flaming for providing the batch command". one of the very positive things about how this is designed, is it's a database of questions and answers, (and even any forum should be actually)..it's not so much about helping a person, but about answering the question they ask(and if they ask a good question it helps them - if they don't then one may comment suggesting a different question or framework for an alternative solution). Also re flaming, like many people saying the same criticism, votes are good there in the design so more compact.

Comment: That said. On that last point re flaming, don't let the fact that your answer is only at -1, lead you to think it wasn't such a bad answer. It was. It is rare for people to pile on downvotes as a sort of flame. (though if they did then notice it is a lot neater than traditional flaming).

Comment: Looks like the flame comment has since been removed but it was on this post: http://superuser.com/questions/645730/batch-repacking-zip-archives-into-7z/645749